# Newton Raphson in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, implicit, newtons-method

I would like to implement the following: ive written a script that executes the Newton Raphson algorithm for my specific function. Now I would like to write a script that repeats itself using the previous found zero as my next intial starting point:

```
x=zeros(1,31);
for i=1:31
    x(i)=(i-1)/10;
end
y0=0;
for i=1:length(x)
    y0=newton(x(i),y0)
end
```

So, I want this script to execute newton(x,y0). So it will start with newton(0,0), it will find a new value y0 and then I want the script to execute newton(0.1,y0) etc. I want these values to be displayed in a table together with the number of iterates that was needed to find the value y0.

I hope my question is clear. Thanks in regards.

Again: I have a vector x with elements 0, 0.1, 0.2, ...,3
When I implement x(i) with initial value y0 newton(x,y) will give me a value. Then I want the script to execute newton(x,y) again with value x(2) for x and the previous found y0.So I need some kind of loop, but I can't get it done .. :(

**EDIT**
This is my `newton`-function:

```
function nulpunt=newton(x,y0)

tolerantie=1e-8;
iteraties=0;

while (abs(functie1(y0,x))>tolerantie)
    y0=y0-functie1(y0,x)/afgeleide_functie1(y0);
    iteraties=iteraties+1;
end

if iteraties==100;
    fprintf('Maximaal aantal iteraties bereikt')
else
    fprintf('De benadering van het nulpunt y*(%.2f) is %.4f gevonden in %d iteraties.\n',x,y0,iteraties)
end
end
```

Comment: Does your function also return the number   of iterates needed to find `y0`?

Comment: 1.) Have you considered placing the function inside a `for` or `while`-loop? 2.) Where do you want the # of iterations and `y0` values to be printed? On screen, in a file?

Comment: on screen, how would I set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop should already use the previous `y0` every consecutive time it operates.
If you want to display the `y0` and the number of iterations in the Matlab command window, you first need to change the `newton`-function to return not just `y0` but also the number of iterations, `iteraties`:

```
function [nulpunt, iteraties]=newton(x,y0)
```

Also, your function should actually return the final `y0`as `nulpunt`:

```
if iteraties==100;
    fprintf('Maximaal aantal iteraties bereikt')
    nulpunt = 0; % in this case, no solution was found, return the baseline value;
else
    fprintf('De benadering van het nulpunt y*(%.2f) is %.4f gevonden in %d iteraties.\n',x,y0,iteraties)
    nulpunt = y0;
end
```

to display the number of iterations and `y0` after each execution of `newton`, add these two lines after you call the function:

```
[y0, iteraties] = newton(x(i),y0);
disp(['This point was found: ',num2str(y0)])
disp(['It took ',num2str(iteraties),' iterations.'])
```

This may actually be redundant, as your function already outputs which `y0` it found and how long that took.

Comment: In matlab i get the error that ''nulpunt'' is not assigned during the call. Furthermore, the newton function itself works fine as long as you give it a value for x and y0. The problem is that I want a loop that given a value of x and y0 it uses the found value as the new y0

Comment: Try again. Your function actually needs to assign a value to `nulpunt`- I assume, you want `y0` for that. You should already have on-screen output of your solution. As long as you are inside the loop, the value for `y0` will be overwritten after each call to `newton` hence being used as the starting value for the next run.